# Should I edit those pesky empty tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Every day I plan to grab a couple of empty tag wikis and edit them to provide at least a reasonable popup information to users of Super User.

Where possible, I plan to write an extended full wiki section, but my efforts are going mostly to the excerpt. Not to say I plan to ignore the full wiki section, simply that I don't plan to write extensive information there unless time permits.

However, I don't yet have editing privileges. I'm comfortable with that, but it means someone else will be required to review my edits and either accept, edit, or reject them.

I'm asking if this is ok with everyone else.

Comment: Been wanting to do that for ages. Just continue and... Thank you!

Comment: Ok. folks. That's good to know. Cheers.

Comment: It's better to give someone review work to do than to leave the entire job for them ... and good tag wikis may help users apply tags more accurately, which will increase the value of both the tags and the site as a whole.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go for it! Any time a user wants to take the initiative to help improve the site like this, we totally support their efforts. It's pretty easy for moderators and users with high enough reputation to approve tag wiki edit suggestions, so please, go right ahead! We will support you in your efforts to make the site better.

Answer (score 14):

Excellent! Do refer to the guidance at

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/

1. The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
2. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
3. Concentrate on what a tag means to *your* community.
4. Provide basic guidance on *when to use* the tag.
5. Remember some tags are common knowledge.

Comment: Ah. Nice to be remembered of 3 and particularly 4. Thanks.